# Web2py conditionally readable field

Tags: field, web2py

Complete newbie to web2py... I want to make the check box at the bottom of the form appear conditionally only if a user is an admin-user. How can I address the name of the field so that I can change if a a non admin user doesn't see it?

I'm using a for loop to have a looping variable to reference, not sure that i need it...

```
## create all tables needed by Technical Request Form
db.define_table('technical_request',
Field('uuid', 'string', default=uuid.uuid4(), readable=False, writable=False),
Field('firstname', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='All Fields are Required!'), label="First Name"),
Field('lastname', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='All Fields are Required!'), label="Last Name"),
Field('phone', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='All Fields are Required!'), label="Phone Number"),
Field('email', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='All Fields are Required!'), label="Email"),    
Field('issue_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='All Fields are Required!'),label="Subject"),
Field('about_issue', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='All Fields are Required!'), label="Description of issue "),
Field('issue', 'upload', label="Attach Files "),
Field('request_processed', 'boolean', default=False, readable = False),
auth.signature)

for field in db.technical_request:
  if field.name == 'request_processed' and auth.has_group_membership("systemadmin"):
    field.readable = True
```

[image]

This is the check box I want to hide ....

- **Follow up question** *

Is there a way I can conditionally add the Field?

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop -- you can just access the field directly via its name:

```
db.technical_request.request_processed.readable = auth.has_group_membership("systemadmin")
```

Or just do it when defining the field:

```
Field('request_processed', 'boolean', default=False,
      readable=auth.has_group_membership("systemadmin"))
```

Comment: I've tried this approach but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to conditionally add the field? In C I can have a preprocessor directive `#ifdef` to jump certain parts of code...

Comment: I've also tried hard coding the readable property to `False` and it still appears :|

Comment: My guess is you are using the built-in `appadmin` functionality, which ignores the `readable` and `writable` attributes (like the `admin` app, it is only intended for someone with complete control of the system). Otherwise, there must be a problem is some code you haven't shown. You might instead consider using [this functionality](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Application-Management-via-privileged-users--Experimental-).